# SCALA list partition on basis of string

Tags: scala

I have the data collected to my List , difficulty I am facing in partitioning the list after a certain String.
    In the below data , I need to spilt the list into two parts on the basis on `digit=11` , Ideally it should iterate and wherever it encounters that list contains `digit=11` , that should be the last element of first partition. 
    I tried to used partition function in scala but it stands good only with index no , in my case I need to make it work with a string as partition element.

### Input:

```
 ListBuffer(Mar 28 07:29:53.570873 mcuReadMsg() msg.type=0x1e-MCU_DigitInd  
    msg.status=0 seqNo=0 ctlLegNo=0 confNo=0 legNo=0 digit=0 incarnation_no=0 
    recording_vad=0 g729_channel_count=0 g722_channel_count=0
    , Mar 28 07:29:54.390835 mcuReadMsg() msg.type=0x1e-MCU_DigitInd  m 
     msg.status=0 seqNo=0 ctlLegNo=0 confNo=0 legNo=0 digit=11 incarnation_no=0 
     recording_vad=0 g729_channel_count=0 g722_channel_count=0
    , Mar 28 07:31:14.071779 mcuReadMsg() msg.type=0x1e-MCU_DigitInd msg.status=0 seqNo=0 ctlLegNo=0 confNo=1 legNo=1 digit=4 incarnation_no=0 recording_vad=0 g729_channel_count=0 g722_channel_count=0
     , Mar 28 07:31:14.951480 mcuReadMsg() msg.type=0x1e-MCU_DigitInd  
     msg.status=0 seqNo=0 ctlLegNo=0 confNo=1 legNo=1 digit=11 incarnation_no=0 recording_vad=0  g729_channel_count=0 g722_channel_count=0
       )
```

### Expected Output:

Partition 1 :

```
         ListBuffer(Mar 28 07:29:53.570873 mcuReadMsg() msg.type=0x1e-MCU_DigitInd  
         msg.status=0 seqNo=0 ctlLegNo=0 confNo=0 legNo=0 digit=0 incarnation_no=0 
         recording_vad=0 g729_channel_count=0 g722_channel_count=0
         , Mar 28 07:29:54.390835 mcuReadMsg() msg.type=0x1e-MCU_DigitInd  m 
         msg.status=0 seqNo=0 ctlLegNo=0 confNo=0 legNo=0 digit=11 incarnation_no=0 
         recording_vad=0 g729_channel_count=0 g722_channel_count=0)
```

Partition 2 :

```
      ListBuffer(Mar 28 07:31:14.071779 mcuReadMsg() msg.type=0x1e-MCU_DigitInd msg.status=0 seqNo=0 ctlLegNo=0 confNo=1 legNo=1 digit=4 incarnation_no=0 recording_vad=0 g729_channel_count=0 g722_channel_count=0
        , Mar 28 07:31:14.951480 mcuReadMsg() msg.type=0x1e-MCU_DigitInd   
        msg.status=0 seqNo=0 ctlLegNo=0 confNo=1 legNo=1 digit=11 incarnation_no=0 
        recording_vad=0  g729_channel_count=0 g722_channel_count=0
        )
```

### Code:

```
     val lines = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines 
     val strList55 = ListBuffer[String]()
     val strList55_New = ListBuffer[String]()
      val regex844 =("-MCU_DigitInd").r 
       val ll1 =  for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
       regex844.findFirstIn(line) match {
                                    case Some(text) => (strList55+=line+"\n")
                                    case None => null
    }
    }
     println(strList55)
     val regex844 =("digit=11").r
     val partition_List = strList55.partition 
    (regex844.findFirstIn(line) match {
      case Some(text)  => (strList_New +=line+"\n")
      case _ => false)
    }}}
```

Comment: That's not a [mcve]. That's a string representation of what could have been an mcve. Please provide the code that generates the input data, the first code block contains unparseable nonsense.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Hi Andrey , I had added the actual code only , first list (input data) gets created from strList55 and then i am trying to partition but unable to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use [span](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableLike.html#span(p:A=%3EBoolean):(Repr,Repr)) in combination with head/tail to move the first element of second partition to the end of the first partition.

```
def span(list: ListBuffer[String]): (ListBuffer[String], ListBuffer[String]) = {
  if(list.isEmpty)
    (ListBuffer(), ListBuffer())
  else list.span(condition) match {
      case (first, ListBuffer()) => (first, ListBuffer())
      case (first, second) => (first ++ ListBuffer(second.head), second.tail)
  }
}

def partitions(list: ListBuffer[String]): List[ListBuffer[String]] = span(list) match {
  case (_, ListBuffer()) => List(list)
  case (partition, rest) => partition :: partitions(rest)
}

val input = ListBuffer("11 digit=1", "12 digit=2", "13 digit=11", "21 digit=11", "31", "32 digit=11", "41 digit=11", "51", "52")

println(partitions(input).mkString("\n"))
```

Comment: Can you give the expression for the same. ??

Comment: @Svitovyda I agree with Andrey , it would be better if you can push the actual logic that does the same. Meanwhile i will try to understand how it can be implemented.

Comment: @Andrewloran, updated with the code example. Not sure if you really need ListBuffer, with list it would be easier and better for performance:`val partition1 = first :: second.head`

Comment: The code should be a recursive one , creating multiple partitions for each occurence of matched character. Can you update the same as Answer ??

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts.